# radio buttons post show value even none of the buttons are checked how to validate this?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have a registration form wich has a gender radio option showing male or female. in the HTML none are checked because i want the user to check one. like this:

```
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios1" value="female">Female
</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios2" value="male">Male
</label>
```

I submit data trough jquery ajax. The strange thing is that the post of al inputs shows

[gender] => male if you submit the form with none of the 2 options checked

So how can i validate this if it never posts empty?

*I want to return a error if no option is selected so it forces a user to select a right gender..

Comment: the problem is obviously in your ajax code, not the HTML above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One really quick way of doing this is defaulting to a choice in the UI. This makes sure that the value is non-empty because you can't "uncheck" a radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios1" value="female" checked> Female
```

Edit: 
Write your own submit function, and bind it to your submit button's onclick()

```
function submit() {
  if (!$("#optionsRadios1").prop("checked") && !$("#optionsRadios2").prop("checked")) {
    alert("please select a gender");
  }
  else {
    //Whatever you do to submit
  }
}
```

Comment: thats true, but not what I want. Because i want to force the user to select a gender so if none is selected i want to return a error message...

Comment: Can you just write your own onclick() function and do the check there? See example code.

Answer (score 0):

**The following code will validate your form on the client side**
This validation will only allow the form to be submitted if one of the gender is selected. If none of the radio button is submitted then it will display an alert message and stop the form from redirecting to action.php.

```
<form name='whatever' onsubmit='return validate();' method='POST' action='action.php'>
    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios1" onchange='validate()' value="female"> Female
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="optionsRadios2" onchange='validate()' value="male"> Male
    </label>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function validate(){
    var feObj=document.getElementById("optionsRadios1");
    var maleObj=document.getElementById("optionsRadios2");
    if (feObj.checked){
        return true;
    }
    if (maleObj.checked){
        return true;
    }
    alert ("Please select a gender");
    return false;
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: yes.. is it not possible with jquey? .. but the point is.. is there no other way exept javascript?

Comment: also if a user selects nothing.. still a wrong var will be posted.. im searching a way to post empty so i can see user did not select a option - like on www.facebook.com

Comment: Yes you can validate the code both on the server side and client side. You can validate on the client side using javascript/jquery on the server side using php or other server side scripting language. 

to validate the above code with jquery just replace maleObj.checked or feObj.checked with $("#optionsRadios2").attr('checked'). 

In order to check if nothing is selected from the radio options, you would have to validate the whole form.

Comment: I have edited the answer for you. I think that is what you are looking for.