# Radio button validaton

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a couple of radio buttons to validate using JavaScript/HTML, but I am having problems. The piece of script I am having trouble with is as follows -

```
        if ( ( RegistrationForm.sexm[0].checked == false ) && ( RegistrationForm.sexf[1].checked == false )) 
        {
            alert( "Please select your sex" ); 
            return false;
        }
```

Basically I want it to return an alert if neither radio button options are selected. At the moment when submitted the form is refreshing itself and not providing any alerts. Any advice would be appreciated!

The relevant HTML I have been provided to work with is -

```
<form id="RegistrationForm" onsubmit="ValidateForm()" action="">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Registration Form</legend>
    <label for="username">User Name: </label> 
    <input type="text" class="input" id="username"/><br />
    <label for="password">Password: </label> 
    <input type="password" class="input" id="password"/><br />
    <label for="repassword">Re-Type Password: </label> 
    <input type="password" class="input" id="repassword"/><br />
    <label for="email">Email Address: </label> 
    <input type="text" class="input" size="30" id="email"/><br />
    <label>Age: </label> 
    <select id ="age" name="age">
        <option value=""> --- </option>
        <option value="0-18">0-18</option>
        <option value="18-30">18-30</option>
        <option value="30-50">30-50</option>
        <option value="50+">50+</option>
    </select><br/>
    <label for="sexm">Sex:</label>
    <input type="radio" id="sexm" name="sex" value="male" />Male<br/>
    <label for="sexf">&nbsp; </label>
    <input type="radio" id="sexf" name="sex" value="female" />Female<br/>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree"  id="agree" value="agree"/>
    <label for="agree">I accept the <a href="">terms and cond</a>.</label> <br/>
    <label>&nbsp; </label> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /> 
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You are using `&&` in if. So it'll go in `IF` only when both not selected. Have you tried by not selecting any of 'em.

Comment: Can u pls have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262432/radio-buttons-post-show-value-even-none-of-the-buttons-are-checked-how-to-valida

Comment: Yeah thats what I am after, I only want an alert if neither box is selected. However even when leaving them both blank, I do not get an alert message. Sorry if I have misunderstood what you mean here!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a radio button is selected in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in your javascript `<script>` tag

```
function ValidateForm () {
   if ( ( document.getElementById("sexm").checked == false ) && ( document.getElementById("sexm").checked == false )) 
   {
      alert( "Please select your sex" ); 
      return false;
   } else {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Replace it with your code

```
if ( ( RegistrationForm.sexm[0].checked == false ) && ( RegistrationForm.sexf[1].checked == false )) 
{
    alert( "Please select your sex" );
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to check whether your user has selected any value or not, if not, than throw an alert and use `return false` to prevent your form being submitted.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/va7rP/3/)

```
var ischecked = null;
var radios = document.getElementsByName('sex');
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
          if (radios[i].checked) {
           ischecked = radios[i];
   }
}
if(ischecked==null) {
    alert('Please choose your Sex');
    return false;
}
```

Save the above code in the function, and call it on submit of your form.

---

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/va7rP/2/) (Validate on submit)

> Note: You need to use `onsubmit="return ValidateForm();"`

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
var o = document.getElementById('sexm');
var t = document.getElementById('sexf');

if ( (o.checked == false ) && (t.checked == false ) )
{
alert ("please select your sex" );

return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>
```